# Post a selected option via ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, select

Assuming I have a `form` with a `select`, how can I send the selected value of the input via an ajax call to my server?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php"
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your question a little bit, placing the question at the beginning and removing some (for the question) unnecessary code. If you are not happy with my edit, feel free to undo it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, an easy solution would be to use its [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: $('select#meal').serialize()
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

The nice thing about this solution is that you do not have to worry about encoding or the select allowing multiple selections.

Note that I assumed some HTML like this:

```
<select id="meal" name="meal">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then, in your PHP script, you can simply access the value using the name of the input (in this case "meal") as the key in the  `$_POST` array:

```
$meal = $_POST['meal'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the data you want to send to your php file.

It should look something like this:

```
type:"POST",
data:"mealid="mealVariableHere
url:"test2.php"
```

Then you access the mealid in your php script in the $_POST variable.

Comment: i think that this cannot work in my case because my data is array.
if only i could name somehow this:
var sel = document.getElementById('mealid'); name=meal
in order to get it from php like this $_POST['meal'];

Comment: But if you don't add the data field, then you are not posting any data. If you want the php script to receive your mealid then you have to post it to the script by defining it in the data argument in your ajax request, like this (data:"name1=value1&name2=value2") just as I showed over. And you say that your data is an array, what data are you talking about?

Comment: in test2.php i have a sqli query that takes data from database and stores it  
in an array.the array is like this:$name={Breakfast, Dinner, Lunch, None}
And then there is a select option with these meals and if someone chooses lunch for example i want sth like this $meal=$_POST[mealid]
echo $meal // output Lunch

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then you have to add an event handler to detect if a user selects a option in your select element. Take a look at this snippet: http://pastie.org/10114986

Comment: thnx a lot!i finally made it working today with clear head...u helped me a lot!